# Highcharts, use error bar with Data Module

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, column-chart

We are using a Highcharts Column chart exactly like this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/data/rows/

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Data input as row arrays'
    },

    data: {
        rows: [
            [null, 'Ola', 'Kari'], // series names
            ['Apples', 1, 5], // category and values
            ['Pears', 4, 4], // category and values
            ['Oranges', 3, 2] // category and values
        ]
    }
});
```

});

So for the chart data we are not using series but data rows.

Is there a way to add an Error Bar to this Column chart, and how can this be done?

Thankz,
walter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been struggling with this myself for a while and I've finally figured it out.
The trick is to define the series and give them an id. 
After that you can link the errorbars to the right series.

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Data input as row arrays'
    },

    tooltip: {
        shared: true
    },


    data: {
        rows: [
            [null, 'Ola', 'Kari'], // series names
            ['Apples', 1, 5], // category and values
            ['Pears', 4, 4], // category and values
            ['Oranges', 3, 2] // category and values
        ]
    },
    series: [
        {
            id: '0'
        },
        {
            id: '1'
        },
        {
            type: 'errorbar',
            data: [[0, 3], [1, 3],[2, 1]],
            linkedTo: '0'
        },
        {
            type: 'errorbar',
            data: [[0, 6], [2, 5],[3, 2]],
            linkedTo: '1'
        }
    ]
});
```

});

See the updated the fiddle for the example:
http://jsfiddle.net/6k7ee0cu/1/